# Oracle pivot issue

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have table t1 consist of 2 column search_I'd and total

```
Search_I'd         Total
25                         2
27                         2
28                         2
31                         4
--------                  ---------
```

When I use pivot with pivot_in_clause and i pass explicit list (25, 27, 28, 31 ) it work fine

But when I use subquery in  pivot_in_clause then it give me an error ora-0096 missing expression

So I use pivot xml in query then I got result set as an

```
SEARCH_ID_XML 
 (XMLTYPE)
```

I want an output as

```
25      27   28   31.......... 
 2      2     2    4.........
```

Using sub query

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: subquery  is not supported  in pivot  except for xml output.

Comment: The pivoting that did work for you is called *static* pivoting. The pivoting you want, with the number of resulting columns unknown until the actual data is inspected, is called *dynamic* pivoting. It can be done, but there are a few questions. (1) **Why** do you want the output in that format? (2) If really needed, it is often best done in your reporting application, not in SQL. Do you use a reporting application? (3) Dynamic SQL is an advanced topic, do you have the necessary expertize for it?

Comment: I am facing the issue so i am finding the solution

Comment: I think you need the dynamic pivot.